# apache2 rewrite rule without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

This below rewrite redirects `localhost` to `http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1` but I want that localhost on browser should not be changed but the page will come form the above link.

I am using this rewrite rule on my Apache conf:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This below rewrite redirects `localhost` to
>   `http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1` but I want that localhost on
>   browser should not be changed but the page will come form the above
>   link.

If you want to load a page from elsewhere without chaining the URL, [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is the wrong tool for the job. Use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead. First enable it in Apache like this; example assumes you are on Ubuntu 12.04 but should work on most any Linux Apache install

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Then set this to enable a reverse proxy from your root path of `/` to `http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1`:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  # Proxy specific settings
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:** Seems like [`mod_proxy` and query strings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for the destination do not mix; emphasis mine:

> This directive allows remote servers to be mapped into the space of
>   the local server; the local server does not act as a proxy in the
>   conventional sense, but appears to be a mirror of the remote server.
>   The local server is often called a reverse proxy or gateway. The path
>   is the name of a local virtual path; url is a partial URL for the
>   remote server **and cannot include a query string.**

So if there is anyway you could set another page—maybe on `localhost`—that would bounce it behind the scenes. Meaning this happens on `localhost`:

```
ProxyPass / bounce.php
```

And then the file, `bounce.php` could have this line in it:

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1');
?>
```

Which would allow `mod_proxy` to have a valid destination. And then the PHP file does the redirect? Hard to say, but the query string on your destination server is the issue.

Comment: One issue i forgot to mention "on localhost I have apache running" and on [link](example.com) nginx is running.

So I am now getting 404 Not Found error with above configuration on localhost

Comment: `Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_http already enabled
ERROR: Module enabled does not exist!`

But I am still getting 404 not Found page when hitting localhost

Comment: curl gives me this
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 06:49:29 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Comment: @JakeGould


_ProxyPass_ / (http://www.example.com) [Working]
ProxyPass / (http://www.example.com/?id=211&test=1) [css/image/js] not loading