# How to write a rewriterule in apache2 to make a url fetch page from other url but the address bar should stay the same?

Tags: apache, http, web

I am looking to create a friendly url example: https://example.com/contact instead of the current url https://example.com/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1. I tried this something like this `ScriptAlias "/contact"  "submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1"` also enabled the mod_alias but it's not working any suggestions how can I fix it?
I cannot use proxypass for this, as I am not allowed to use that.

Here is what is tried so far:

```
ScriptAlias "/contact"  "submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1"
```

which give me 404 error page.

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /contact(.*)$ https://www.example.com.au%{ENV:ServerUrlSuffix}/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1 [L]
```

which is just redirecting me to other url.

What I need is when I search this url https://www.example.com/contact I should get page from this url https://example.com/submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1 but the address bar should keep showing https://www.example.com/contact

Comment: Double submit prevention uses a redirect after form submit. So it is not a big deal. With HTTP POST you could remove the parameters. And if the contact page would distinguish between GET and POST, you could use the same URL.

Comment: Can you explain that with an example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I searched for "*apache redirect without changing url*" and found many answers describing how to do an internal redirect, for eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298530/redirect-without-changing-url-apache, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171293/mod-rewrite-forwarding-without-changing-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url ... The same search shows some answers using `mod_proxy`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321014/apache2-rewrite-rule-without-changing-url ... have you tried those solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect Without changing URL Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298530/redirect-without-changing-url-apache)

Comment: No https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298530/redirect-without-changing-url-apache this is not working, and as I mentioned use of proxy pass is prohibited.

Comment: I think you maybe did not read the links I suggested.

Comment: I red them also implemented them, but the url is still ending up to 404

Comment: Nobody can help if you don't tell us what you've tried, and what happened.  Edit your question, show the rule(s) you tried, and describe the results.